# Forms & Posting - Multiple Data

Tags: php, mysql

So I was looking at some other posts on this site and came across the code below (EDIT of my code) which works perfectly apart from when I submit I get an error code of: **Notice: Undefined index: id in /customers/0/2/e/richardbrown.name/httpd.www/debt/payment_process.php on line 17**  for each result.

```
<form method="post" action="payment_process.php">
<table border="0">';
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM debt_accounts LEFT JOIN debt_companies ON accounts_company=companies_id WHERE accounts_amount > 0 ORDER BY accounts_company ASC");

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo'<tr>
<td width="200" align="left"><input type="text" name="payment[][id]" value="'.$row['accounts_id'].'" /></td>
<td width="100" align="right"><input type="text" name="payment[][amount]"  value="25.00" /></td>
</tr>';                 

}   

echo'</table><br /> <br /><input type="submit" /></form>


if ( isset( $_POST['payment'] ) )
{
    echo '<table>';
    foreach ( $_POST['payment'] as $diam )
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '  <td>', $diam['id'], '</td>';
        echo '  <td>', $diam['amount'], '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: Process script to do what?

Comment: all the name fields need to be unique or in an array, so the name field needs to be payment_id[] etc. This can then be processed when it is sent

Comment: take a look at [link](http://www.richardbrown.name/debt/payment.php) that is the list from the database, so once I click submit I want to be able to process the 11 results to be able to enter the data... I have used a foreach ob the paymen_id but doesnt seem to work?

Comment: You want the total of all 11 inputs? Plus, your other comment below *"but the $_POST['payment_amount'] is currently amount 11 on the form page when I want it to be based on what I input?"* is confusing; almost contradictive.

Comment: sorry I will see if I can explain some more.... [link](http://www.richardbrown.name/debt/payment.php) is the form I want, where it selects all the records from my accounts with a balance over 0. I then went to be able to change the amount I want to pay for each account, so it can be different, then process this... and add the payments to the database on the process form... but I can not get the correct amount to work, on the form change say record 9 to something different and submit and you will see what I mean by it only remembers the last record on the form

Comment: I posted an answer for you below.

Comment: *I posted an answer for you below. –  Fred -ii- 52 mins ago* - Where are we with this?

Comment: That was still not achieving what I wanted. Maybe it was the way I explained it But I searched a bit longer on this site and have edited my code above with a solution I found that works apart from the error code I have also stated

Answer (score 1):

Change this line from your form element:

```
name="payment_amount"
```

to be an array:

```
name="payment_amount[]"
```

Then, modify your `foreach` to read as:

```
foreach ($_POST['payment_amount'] as $value) {
  echo $value . "<br>";
}
```

- You were using the wrong POST array => `name="payment_id[]"`

To add them all up, should you want to do that, use:

```
foreach ($_POST['payment_amount'] as $value) {

   echo $value . "<br>";

   $total += $value; 

} 

   echo $total;
```

or

```
$total = array_sum($_POST['payment_amount']);
```

Answer (score 0):

your solution is :
name="payment_id[]" in your form

and server side (payment_process.php)
you use a foreach loop with the $_POST['payment_id'][].

Comment: ok so I added the payment_id[] but now when you process you get a list, but the $_POST['payment_amount'] is currently amount 11 on the form page when I want it to be based on what I input?

Comment: just because you have to do the same with name="payment_amount[]" in your form. Each has to be an array in your form. You could then use "foreach($_POST['payment_amount'] as $value )" in your payment_process.php